# National Weather Service API Internal server error

Tags: c#, weather-api

I keep getting error 500 when trying to get data using their new API, even when I include UserAgent string that they request: https://forecast-v3.weather.gov/documentation

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.weather.gov/points/40,-90/forecast/hourly");

request.UserAgent = "WeatherTest/v1.0 (http://www.website.com/; Email@email.com)";

// exception occurs here
using (Stream stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
{
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        var jsonData = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

But I can use the endpoint on a browser just fine using the same url: https://api.weather.gov/points/40,-90/forecast/hourly

I have also tested this code with another API (Weather Underground) and it works, but my boss wants me to use National Weather Service api instead. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation you provided gives you an answer:

> Content Negotiation
>
> The API will use Accept headers to modify the
> response returned. See the FAQ tab for more information. Parameters
> include: Version of the API, defaults to the oldest Format of the
> response, default in specifications An example of the Accept header
> would be "Accept: application/vnd.noaa.dwml+xml;version=1"

Add:

`request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.noaa.dwml+json;version=1");` and you'll get a JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

Error 500 is Internal Server Error - this means that the server knows that it errored and recorded it.

Since your method of retrieving data is working for a different API, it seems most likely that the NWS API is quietly refusing the service on purpose. Perhaps it doesn't like the email string you provided, or so on and so forth.

When it comes to third party APIs like this one, your best bet is (1) defer to the manual, if one exists (eg, "RTFM") or (2) to experiment a bit and try different things until you find something that works.

For example, I found that many services - APIs included - did not like one of my email addresses in the format of username@subdomain.domain.com and would refuse service. Only with experimentation was I able to figure this out.

Comment: Or 3) contact them and let them know their API is giving an error

Comment: @mason True, possible, but unlikely to obtain assistance